# SQLite限定・条件分岐させたい

Tags: sql, sqlite

お世話になります。

SQLite限定で、UPDATEで更新する値を、条件により
分岐させたいと考えています。
Webで検索すると、transact-sqlらしきものではできると
見つかるのですが、SQLiteでは使えるのでしょうか？

やりたいのは、下記のような内容になります。

```
SELECT MIN(index) FROM list WHERE index > (SELECT t_index FROM conf)

//値がない場合
if (false)
{
    UPDATE conf SET t_index=(SELECT MIN(index) FROM list WHERE index > 0)
    // 1以上の値の中から最小値をセット
}
// 値がある場合
else
{
    UPDATE conf SET t_index=(SELECT MIN(index) FROM list WHERE index > (SELECT t_index FROM conf))
}
```

つまり、conf.t_indexよりも大きい値がlist.indexにあれば、その中の最小値を
conf.t_indexにセットし、大きい数がなければlist.indexの最小値をセットしたいのです。

初心者なので、解らないためこのような質問になっていますが、
ソースコード側で分岐させなくても、SQLのみで実現できそうな気はします。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE式で機械的に書いてみました。
indexが予約語なので、ダブルクォートで囲んでいます。

```
UPDATE conf
SET t_index =
( 
  SELECT MIN("index")
  FROM list
  WHERE "index" >
  CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT "index" FROM list WHERE "index" > (SELECT t_index FROM conf))
  -- 値がある場合、conf.t_indexより大きなlist.indexの最小値をセット
  THEN ( SELECT t_index FROM conf)
  -- 値がない場合、1以上のlist.indexの最小値をセット
  ELSE 0
  END
)
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
試してみたところ、値がある場合にはうまくいきますが、
値がなく、最小値がセットされる時点でNullが返ってきてしまいます。
これは何か原因なのでしょうか。

Comment: EXISTS句のサブクエリに集計関数を使ったことが原因のバグです。修正しました。

Comment: rouさん、ありがとうございました。
おかげで、希望通りの機能を実現することができました。
とても勉強になりました。
今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。